# Interpreting Silhouette plot

Tags: clustering

Can someone help me interpret this silhouette plot?

[image]

The things that come up on my mind are:

- Some clusters are very small
- Orange cluster is very big
- Pink, dark green and light green clusters are better than orange cluster
- In general, clusters have medium quality (avg silhouette is about 0.38)

But is there anything else that I could conclude from the image?

For example, would there be any reasoning to conclude that orange cluster should be divided into two clusters?